# My object is moving too fast in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, spline

I am suppose to implement a CatMull Rom Spline, and I have it implemented, but the sphere moves to the points extremely fast. I thought if I used Time.DeltaTime it would slow it down, but it moves too rapidly.

**Function to compute point on curve:**

```
Vector3 ComputePointOnCatmullRomCurve(float u, int segmentNumber)
{
    // TODO - compute and return a point as a Vector3       
    // Points on segment number 0 start at controlPoints[0] and end at controlPoints[1]
    // Points on segment number 1 start at controlPoints[1] and end at controlPoints[2]
    //       etc...

    Vector3 point = new Vector3();

    float c0 = ((-u + 2f) * u - 1f) * u * 0.5f;
    float c1 = (((3f * u - 5f) * u) * u + 2f) * 0.5f;
    float c2 = ((-3f * u + 4f) * u + 1f) * u * 0.5f;
    float c3 = ((u - 1f) * u * u) * 0.5f;

    Vector3 p0 = controlPoints[(segmentNumber - 1) % NumberOfPoints];
    Vector3 p1 = controlPoints[segmentNumber % NumberOfPoints];
    Vector3 p2 = controlPoints[(segmentNumber + 1) % NumberOfPoints];
    Vector3 p3 = controlPoints[(segmentNumber + 2) % NumberOfPoints];

    point.x = (p0.x * c0) + (p1.x * c1) + (p2.x * c2) + (p3.x * c3);
    point.y = (p0.y * c0) + (p1.y * c1) + (p2.y * c2) + (p3.y * c3);
    point.x = (p0.z * c0) + (p1.z * c1) + (p2.z * c2) + (p3.z * c3);

    return point;
}
```

**Update Function: **

```
void Update () 
{
    // TODO - use time to determine values for u and segment_number in this function call
    // 0.5 Can be used as u
    time += DT;

    segCounter++;

    Vector3 temp = ComputePointOnCatmullRomCurve(time, segCounter);
    transform.position = temp;
}
```

**Variables:**

```
const int NumberOfPoints = 8;
Vector3[] controlPoints;

const int MinX = -5;
const int MinY = -5;
const int MinZ = 0;

const int MaxX = 5;
const int MaxY = 5;
const int MaxZ = 5;

float time = 0;
const float DT = 0.01f;
public static int segCounter = 0;
```

EDIT: Sorry the calculations, and all of that is correct. It's straight from the slides, I just need help with the update function :(

Comment: Are you using Time.deltaTime somewhere? Or can make it slower with Time.deltaTime*0.01f

Comment: Multiply the computed value by a speed variable: `public float speed = 3` then `Vector3 temp = ComputePointOnCatmullRomCurve(time, segCounter) * Time.deltaTime * speed`. You can change/reduce the `speed` variable from the Editor during run-time and you'll find the proper value to use for speed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Time.deltaTime` allows you to be **framerate independent**. This means that if the framerate drops, or a frame takes longer than the others, your object will adapt the moving distance to keep a constant speed. This is generally a good idea.

Back to your case: Basically you want to pass a position to your function. You currently pass the time. If your catmull rom considers that 0 is the start and 1 is the destination, then after exactly 1 second, you will be at the end of the spline. (Note that this is where being framerate independent is interesting: Whatever the frame rate is. you reach the end in one second). Now, how to convert from time to position. Easy

> position = time*speed;

Since time is in second, speed is in units per seconds. Say your catmullrom is one unit long. If speed is two, if will take one second to travel it twice. so half a second to travel it. Since you want to lower the speed, you might want to use values below 1. Try this:

```
void Update () 
{
    time += Time.deltaTime;
    var speed = 0.1f;
    var splinePos = speed * time;

    segCounter++;

    Vector3 temp = ComputePointOnCatmullRomCurve(splinePos, segCounter);
    transform.position = temp;
}
```